# Printing numerical value only from BeautifulSoup4 scraped result

Tags: python

I'm trying to "print" only the numerical results of this code. How can I remove the quotes and the percentage from the results?

```
urllong = "http://www.worldgovernmentbonds.com/country/russia/"
pagelong = requests.get(urllong, timeout=5)

souplong = BeautifulSoup(pagelong.content, "html.parser")

resultslong = souplong.find(id="page")
series_elementlong = resultslong.find("div", class_="post-content box mark-links entry-content")
longratelong = series_elementlong.find(class_="w3-center w3-sand")
longrate = longratelong.find("b").contents
print(longrate)
```

Comment: What are your actual and expected outputs?

Comment: '[7.420%]' is the actual, 7.42 is the expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following construction:

```
import re

longrate = "'[7.420%]'"
print([float(token) for token in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)', longrate)])
# Outputs [7.42]
```

This is a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto). You can apply it to some text to find patterns that you can specify inside the expression. In this case, the expression breaks down to

- `\d`: match a number (0-9)
- `+`: one or more times
- `(?:...)`: optionally, match the pattern `...`:

  - `\.`: a point (followed by)
  - `\d+`: a number one or more times

When you apply this expression to `"[7.420%]"`, it'll match the `7.420` substring, since it starts with with one or more numbers, has a point and is followed by one or more numbers.

Comment: How did you get re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+) ? I'm new to coding this is my 2nd day

Comment: Sorry, I've added some explanation. Feel free to ask any more questions!

Comment: How can I remove the brackets around the [7.42]? I need it to subtract from another output I have in my code.

Comment: The value `[7.42]` is a list, and you can access its first element by doing `[7.42][0]`. You can learn this in any Python tutorial.